# Wrapping a pre-initialized pointer in a cython class

Tags: python, c, pointers, cython

I'm trying to use a C library which uses a callback function (callback_function) to provide a pointer to a struct I'd like to wrap (glp_tree).

What is the correct way to initialize an instance with a pointer not created in `__cinit__`? I can't find an example of this pattern in the cython documentation.

I have some working code (see below), which casts the pointer to an integer and back, but I'm not sure this is good practice / sane.

```
cdef extern from "stdint.h":
    ctypedef unsigned long long uint64_t

cdef extern from "glpk.h":
    ctypedef struct glp_tree:
        pass

cdef void callback_func(glp_tree* tree, void *info):
    treeobj = Tree(<uint64_t>tree) // cast to an integer...

cdef class Tree:
    cdef glp_tree* ptr
    def __init__(self, uint64_t ptr):
        self.ptr = <glp_tree*>ptr // ... and back to a pointer
```

Passing the glp_tree object directly seems to work (although it's not what I want to do), but trying to pass the pointer results in a compiler error:

```
Cannot convert 'glp_tree *' to Python object
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `__init__`/`__cinit__` (which always expects Python objects as arguments), you can use a custom `@staticmethod cdef` to create instances:

```
cdef class Tree:
    cdef glp_tree* ptr

    def __init__(self, *args):
        raise TypeError('Cannot create instance from Python')

    @staticmethod
    cdef Tree create(glp_tree* ptr):
        obj = <Tree>Tree.__new__(Tree) # create instance without calling __init__
        obj.ptr = ptr
        return obj
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Switching this to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Casting a pointer to an integer is an option, but then the correct type to use is `uintptr_t`, not `uint64_t` (it's self-documenting and always has the right width for the platform).

The problem is that constructing a `Tree` is a Python operation, as you can clearly see in the `cython -a` output. The input to the constructor has to be converted to Python data structures, and pointers have no obvious conversion.

Comment: This makes sense to me now. You can't pass a pointer to __init__ because it's python, not cython, and there isn't a python equivalent.

Comment: @Snorfalorpagus: and special methods such as `__init__` cannot be `cdef`'d.

Answer (score -1):

This will work

```
cdef class Tree:
    cdef glp_tree* ptr
    def __init__(self, long ptr):
        self.ptr = <glp_tree*>PyLong_AsVoidPtr(ptr)
```

Comment: On 64-bit Windows, `long` is still only 32-bit, so your code won't work.

Comment: So why do u need to penalise me a point for my honest attempt to help this fellow!?