# Cython - Replacement for def __init__() method since Cython's Python functions and methods cannot handle unsigned char arrays with values of 0

Tags: python, c, arrays, cython

all. I have this Cython code example down below where I have an unsigned char array, `a` filled with unsigned integers. When I pass in this array into a Python `def` method, the value of any index after the index containing 0 becomes messed up.

In this example, since the value of 0 was at the 6th index, all succeeding array indices from the array passed into the `__cinit__()` method have incorrect values. This behavior also happens for the `__init__()` method or any function or method using the Python declaration `def`.

However, when the array is passed into any `cdef` or `cpdef` function or method, the values of the array is correct.

So, I have two questions (and note that I am using a .pyx runner file):

1. Am I passing in the array into the `__cinit__()` method incorrectly? Is there another way to do it?
2. Alternatively, is there a Cythonic way of replacing the `def __cinit__()` method? Of course, I could use a workaround and use `cdef` or `cpdef` methods, especially for this simple little example that I'm showing, but I would like to learn whether there is a different way...

**Code:**

```
cdef class Classical:
    def __cinit__(self, unsigned char *b):
        for x in range(0, 12):
            print b[x], " init" # This does not work

    cdef void bar(self, unsigned char *b):
        for x in range(0, 12):
            print b[x], " method" # This works fine

def foo(unsigned char *b):
    for x in range(0, 12):
        print b[x], " function" # This does not work either

cdef unsigned char a[12]
a = [
    83,
    12,
    85,
    31,
    7,
    0,
    91,
    11,
    0,
    12,
    77,
    100
]
Classical(a).bar(a)
foo(a)
```

**Output:**

```
83  init
12  init
85  init
31  init
7  init
0  init
0  init
0  init
0  init
0  init
0  init
0  init
83  method
12  method
85  method
31  method
7  method
0  method
91  method
11  method
0  method
12  method
77  method
100  method
83  function
12  function
85  function
31  function
7  function
0  function
100  function
0  function
0  function
0  function
0  function
0  function
```

Comment: I think @ead's answer is more generally useful, but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695402/wrapping-a-pre-initialized-pointer-in-a-cython-class/ (or one of the many other questions with a similar theme). If you want to initialize from C pointers then you may be better with a staticmethod

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for pointing me in that direction as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All arguments of a def-function are Python objects. A `char *` (the same holds for `unsigned char *`) isn't a Python object, however it is possible to automatically convert (some) Python objects to `char *`. So

```
def foo(char *x):
   ...
```

means for Cython: check that the passed Python object can be converted to a `cdef char *`, perform the conversion and use the result of this conversion in the body of the function.

When calling a def-function with a `char *` (see also this somewhat related [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53763480/5769463)) as argument:

```
cdef char a[12]
....
bar(a) # a decays to char *
```

Cython performs the following: Use automatic conversion of `char *` assuming it is a null-terminated c-string to a bytes-object and pass this temporary bytes-object to the `def`-function `bar`.

That means in your case:

- calling `foo(a)` creates a temporary bytes-object of length 5 (and not 12, because 6th element is `0`), to which the first 5 characters are copied.
- inside of function `foo` the address of this bytes-object's buffer is taken and used as `unsigned char *b`, which has now only 6 elements (including trailing `\0`), so accessing it via `b[6]` is undefined behavior and could end in a segmentation fault.

You can verify that `a` and `b` point to different addresses via

```
print("Address:", <unsigned long long>(&a[0])) # or &b[0]
```

So the problem is actually, that when you call `foo` not the whole array is converted to the temporary `bytes`-object. The conversion from/to `char *` is described in [Cython-documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html#unicode-and-passing-strings). In your case the call should be:

```
foo(a[:12]) #pass the length explicitly, so cython doesn't have to depend on '\0'
```

and now the following is printed:

```
83  function
12  function
85  function
31  function
7  function
0  function
91  function
11  function
0  function
12  function
77  function
100  function
```

---

The situation is different for `cdef`-functions, where `char *` stays `char *` and isn't converted to a Python-object. However, `__cinit__` must be a `def` function and thus in this case usually a `cdef`-factory function is used, as in [the answer pointed out by @DavidW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695402/wrapping-a-pre-initialized-pointer-in-a-cython-class/), e.g.:

```
cdef class Classical:
    ...
    @staticmethod
    cdef Classical create(char* ptr):
        obj = <Classical>Classical.__new__(Classical) # __init__ isn't called!
        # set up obj while using ptr
        ...
        return obj
```

Obviously, `Classical.create` can be only used from Cython code, but on the other hand only Cython-code has pointers!